# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '[x]'

Tags: python

I am trying to make a script that moves all the .txt files in your desktop to desktop/org, the code is as follows:

```
import os
import shutil

userhome = os.path.expanduser('~')
src = userhome + '/Desktop/'
dst = src+ 'org/'

def main(): 
    txtlist = os.listdir(src)
    for file in txtlist:
        sortFiles(file)

def sortFiles(file):        
        if file.endswith(".txt"):
            shutil.move(src+file,dst)   


main()
```

If I execute the .py I get this error: **AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'copy'**. However, if I erase the last line "main()" and I import this script as a module in the python command line and I call .main() from there it works perfectly well. How can I make this work **as a script**?

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python32\org.py", line 3, in <module>
    import shutil
  File "C:\Python32\lib\shutil.py", line 14, in <module>
    import tarfile
  File "C:\Python32\lib\tarfile.py", line 50, in <module>
    import copy
  File "C:\Python32\lib\copy.py", line 61, in <module>
    from org.python.core import PyStringMap
  File "C:\Python32\org.py", line 19, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Python32\org.py", line 12, in main
    sortFiles(file)
  File "C:\Python32\org.py", line 16, in sortFiles
    shutil.move(src+file,dst)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'move'
```

I am using python 3.2

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace of the error please?

Comment: This code worked fine on my Mac under Python 2.7. I presume you call `main()` from your other program as there is no `.move()`.

Comment: This worked fine for me in CentOS provided you have the directories existing!

Comment: Excuse me, I wanted to say .main(). I already edited that on the post. I also added the traceback. I'm using python 3.2 btw

Comment: the directories do exist. If I import this script as a module and call its .main() from the command line it works perfectly well for me. The problem is I can't make it work as an autoexecutable script.

Comment: Your code shows you calling `shutil.move` but the stacktrace shows you called `shutil.copy`. What is your actual code calling?

Comment: Copy the file src to the file or directory dst. If dst is a directory, a file with the same basename as src is created (or overwritten) in the directory specified.

Comment: I pasted an old error trace, excuse me. I already updated it

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Wow, that’s some bad luck. You can understand what’s going on when you look at the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python32\org.py", line 3, in <module>
    import shutil
```

So, the first line that is being executed is `import shutil`. That’s where everything starts going wrong—which is suprising given that it’s a built-in module.

```
  File "C:\Python32\lib\shutil.py", line 14, in <module>
    import tarfile
  File "C:\Python32\lib\tarfile.py", line 50, in <module
    import copy
```

So `shutil` import `tarfile`, which imports `copy`.

```
  File "C:\Python32\lib\copy.py", line 61, in <module>
    from org.python.core import PyStringMap
```

And `copy` has this nice thing that tries to import `PyStringMap` from a module called `org.python.core`. Now, this module usually does not exist, which would cause `copy` to use some alternative code instead: `PyStringMap = None`.

The problem is, that there *is* something called `org`: Your own script, `org.py`. So what happens is that Python tries to find something called `python.core.PyStringMap` in your `org.py`. To be able to go that far, it needs to *execute* the script, including the `main()` call at the end:

```
  File "C:\Python32\org.py", line 19, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Python32\org.py", line 12, in main
    sortFiles(file)
  File "C:\Python32\org.py", line 16, in sortFiles
    shutil.copy(src+file,dst)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'copy'
```

And that leads us to the `shutil.copy` line which is a call to the `shutil` module. As this is the module we are still importing (from the very first line!), its import hasn’t completely yet, so the `copy` function inside does not exist, causing the `AttributeError`.

This is a very unfortunate situation in which the naming of your script caused a circular import for something that doesn’t exist.

You can easily fix this by renaming your script into something else.

Comment: I would also suggest moving the org.py script out of the python32 directory. Only code from the actual distribution should be in this directory.