# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'x'

Tags: python

I was reading loading of modules from [here](http://ivory.idyll.org/articles/advanced-swc/#how-modules-are-loaded-and-when-code-is-executed).

There are two files in one of my directory `mod_a.py` and `mod_b.py`.

`mod_a.py` contains the following

```
print 'at top of mod_a'
import mod_b
print 'mod_a: defining x'
x = 5
```

while `mod_b.py` contains

```
print 'at top of mod_b'
import mod_a
print 'mod_b: defining y'
y = mod_a.x
```

on executing `mod_a.py` file I got the following output:

```
at top of mod_a
at top of mod_b
at top of mod_a
mod_a: defining x
mod_b: defining y
mod_a: defining x
```

However, while executing `mod_b.py` I got the following output:

```
at top of mod_b
at top of mod_a
at top of mod_b
mod_b: defining y
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\Workspace\Problems-2\mod_b.py", line 2, in <module>
    import mod_a
  File "D:\Python\Workspace\Problems-2\mod_a.py", line 2, in <module>
    import mod_b
  File "D:\Python\Workspace\Problems-2\mod_b.py", line 4, in <module>
    y = mod_a.x
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'x'
```

Can anybody please explain this?

Comment: You have a circular import. Don't do that; this is what happens when you do.

Comment: @user2357112, Thanks, I have tried this for learning and practicing. Could you please explain how exactly circular import troubled here?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#how-can-i-have-modules-that-mutually-import-each-other

Comment: I think this answer would help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/744410/2251785

Comment: An exact duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22131139/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-x

Answer (score 1):

The code fails at this one line

```
import mod_a
```

Because it will run though `mod_a.py`, which imports `mod_b.py`, where `mod_a.x` has not yet been defined.

For clarity, see this "trace" of `mod_b`

```
print 'at top of mod_b'
import mod_a # Importing a... 

    print 'at top of mod_a'
    import mod_b # Importing b...

        print 'at top of mod_b'
        import mod_a # ... will happen, but... 
        print 'mod_b: defining y'
        y = mod_a.x                 # error

    print 'mod_a: defining x'
    x = 5

print 'mod_b: defining y'
y = mod_a.x
```

Compared to `mod_a`

```
print 'at top of mod_a'
import mod_b # Importing b...

    print 'at top of mod_b'
    import mod_a # Importing a...

        print 'at top of mod_a'
        import mod_b # Recurses...
        print 'mod_a: defining x'
        x = 5                      # definition

    print 'mod_b: defining y'
    y = mod_a.x                    # it's defined... no error

print 'mod_a: defining x'
x = 5
```