# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Template'

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, numpy

I'm using MacOs with the PyCharm environment, and my project is set to use Python 2.7.10. Now, I have on the first line of my module the line:

```
import numpy as np
```

When I try to run my code, I get the following error:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7 /{path to file}/numpy_exercise.py
 Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/{path to file}/numpy_exercise.py", line 1, in module>
 import numpy as np 
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/__init__.py", line 169, in module>
 from . import polynomial 
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/polynomial/__init__.py", line 20, in module>
 from .polynomial import Polynomial 
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/polynomial/polynomial.py", line 68, in module>
 from .polytemplate import polytemplate 
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/polynomial/polytemplate.py", line 17, in module>
 polytemplate = string.Template(''' AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Template'
```

(note that "module>" was actually in brackets from both sides but because it gets omitted that way I daleted the first bracket so you can see it)

Though in Python 3 it does not happens to me. I looked on the web but couldn't find anything. I have no clue of why this is happening. I'd be glad to get some of your help!

Thank you guys!

Comment: How did you install numpy? Do you happen to have a file in your working directory called `string.py`? I.e. does `/{path to file}/string.py` exist?

Comment: Hi, I installed numpy using pip (terminal), and yes I have a string.py file actually! I'm curious of how is it related to numpy?

Comment: Yes. Change the name of that file. `numpy` is searching your `PYTHONPATH` when it does `import string` somewhere (probably at the top of) `polytemplate.py`. The problem is, your `PYTHONPATH` has your working directory first. It finds `string.py` and imports *that*, but really, it should be importing `string` from the standard library (the path to that is checked after your working directory). You shouldn't name a `.py` file after a standard-library name unless you *want* this to happen.

Comment: Wow I wouldn't think of this! now it works! thank you very much!

Comment: Note, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22131139/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-x?rq=1) was the top-most related question... You should try to do some searching before you post a question. Anyway, most Python programmers will be bitten by this at some point, and usually you'll go down some horrible rabbit-hole trying to figure out why some standard library module isn't installed only to figure out you've accidentally used that name already for one of your own scripts!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga could you post your comment as an answer so Lior Cohen can mark it as solved? Thnx!